# Remove rows with "NA" if present in all column

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi my dataframe consists of rows that have NA's in all the columns and i would like to remove them.

Here's how my dataframe sample looks like:

```
Date       Blk 3    Blk 3    Blk3     Total
           Lvl 2-25 Lvl 2-26 Lvl 2-27 
2019-01-02  1       20       10        31
2019-01-02  NA      NA       NA        NA
2019-01-03  NA      10       30        40
```

and i would like to remove just the 2nd row. and to look like this after removing:

```
Date       Blk 3    Blk 3    Blk3     Total
           Lvl 2-25 Lvl 2-26 Lvl 2-27 
2019-01-02  1       20       10        31
2019-01-03  NA      10       30        40
```

I've tried ways like this:

```
df <- df %>% remove_empty("rows") #using janitor package
```

or

```
df <- df %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
df <- df %>% filter_all(any_vars(complete.cases(.)))
```

or

```
df <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df), ]
```

but none of them works. can someone help me please?

Here is my dput(df):

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17777, 17778, 17779, 17780, 
17781, 17782), class = "Date"), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-25` = c(300, 200, 
600, 600, 250, 800), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-26` = c(400, 120, 400, 3000, 
150, 1200), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-27` = c(500, 90, 120, 300, 800, 200), 
    `Blk 3 Lvl 2-28` = c(80, 800, 150, 500, 1500, 800), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-29` = c(50, 
    300, 1.2, 80, 120, 12), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-30` = c(150, 30, 60, 
    300, 1500, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-31` = c(30, 600, 400, 2000, 
    250, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-32` = c(2000, 3000, 600, 1200, 900, 
    NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-33` = c(250, 200, 200, 150, 250, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-34` = c(1500, 
    5000, 1.2, 3000, 600, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-35` = c(2000, 1500, 
    1500, 3000, 1500, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-36` = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 
    2000, 1500, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-37` = c(400, 800, 3000, 600, 
    1200, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 2-38` = c(600, 1200, 1200, 2000, 800, 
    NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-25` = c(2000, 1200, 900, 3000, 900, NA), 
    `Blk 3 Lvl 5-26` = c(200, 200, 1.2, 400, 600, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-27` = c(800, 
    800, 600, 800, 400, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-28` = c(800, 800, 1.2, 
    800, 2000, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-29` = c(1200, 1200, 800, 600, 
    900, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-30` = c(1500, 1200, 900, 400, 1200, 
    NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-31` = c(400, 800, 1.2, 12, 90, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-32` = c(150, 
    120, 200, 300, 150, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-33` = c(500, 600, 900, 
    300, 900, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-34` = c(300, 300, 1.2, 900, 1200, 
    NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-35` = c(200, 250, 300, 200, 200, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-36` = c(900, 
    1200, 3000, 2000, 1500, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-37` = c(800, 1500, 
    2000, 2000, 3000, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 5-38` = c(600, 200, 3000, 
    80, 400, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-25` = c(900, 400, 1200, 800, 400, 
    NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-26` = c(1500, 800, 3000, 800, 600, NA), 
    `Blk 3 Lvl 7-27` = c(800, 400, 300, 400, 400, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-28` = c(200, 
    200, 200, 30, 12, NA), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-29` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-30` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-31` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-32` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-33` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-34` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-35` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-36` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-37` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Blk 3 Lvl 7-38` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Total = c(23510, 
    27510, 27037.2, 32552, 26172, 3012)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is how my actual dataframe looks like and i would like to remove rows like row 7:
[image: dataframe]

Comment: Since you don't want to count the 1st column for `NA` values you need to do `df[rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df) - 1, ]` Or using `dplyr`, `df %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Lv")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))`

Comment: @RonakShah hi thank you for your fast replies, however nothing changed after i tried that

Comment: Did you assign the result back? `df1 <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df) - 1, ]`. Check `df1` now.

Comment: @RonakShah yes i did assign back to df and the rows returns the same

Comment: Can you update your post with `dput(df)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah it would be a big output but sure i'll take a screenshot

Comment: screenshot wouldn't be helpful. If the dataframe is big you could add only `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @RonakShah Edited my post again. please check. sorry for the troubles

Comment: based on the `dput` that you have shared none of the rows have all the values as `NA`, hence no rows are removed which one would you like to remove?

Comment: @Team9 `df <- subset(df,rowSums(is.na(df)) < ncol(df) )`

Comment: @RonakShah that's impossible when i check my total exists "0" means the row is NA. Refer to the new image that i've edited in my post. thank you

Comment: @AaronParrilla hi thank you for the reply however it's still the same..

Comment: @RonakShah thank you! Your edited comment solves it using dplyr! :) thank you so much.

Comment: You have to exclude the first column of `df` (i.e. the column `Date`). Try `apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there are more than 1 columns which need to excluded in calculation of `NA` values. We could select only the columns which we need and perform `rowSums`

```
cols <- grep("^Blk", names(df))
df[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) != length(cols), ]
```

Or using `dplyr` that would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Blk")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base R` would be to select the columns of interest ('nm1'), loop through the columns with `lapply`, check if they are NA to convert to logical vector, `Reduce` it to single logical vector with `&`, negate (`!`) and subset the rows

```
nm1 <- grep("^Blk", names(df))
df[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[nm1], is.na)),]
```

---

It can also be done with `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[nm1])) > 0,]
```